# AJAX GET - Newest records by time

Tags: php, ajax, json, mysqli, polling

So I've tried various ways of getting new data over the past 5 days and I'm determined to get this notifications system completed as I don't like not finishing something before moving on to something new. I tried local storage but it didn't have the desired affect

So I firstly created the ajax to send the last notification by time to the server side from client side and get any new one for the session user like so.

```
<?  
$user1_id=$_SESSION['id'];
$call="select * from notifications WHERE notification_targetuser='$user1_id' AND notification_status=1 ORDER BY notification_id DESC LIMIT 1";
        $chant=mysqli_query($mysqli,$call) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

            while($notification=mysqli_fetch_array($chant)){
            ?>


            <script type="text/javascript">

function loadIt() {
  var notification_time="<?php echo $notification['notification_time'] ;?>"


$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "viewajax.php?notification_time="+notification_time,   
dataType:"json",
cache: false,
success: function(response){
    if (response.notificiation_time > notification_time) {
      $("#notif_actual_text-"+notification_time).prepend('<div class="notif_ui"><div class="notif_text"><div  id="notif_actual_text-'+response['notification_id']+'" class="notif_actual_text"><img border=\"1\" src=\"userimages/cropped'+response['notification_triggeredby']+'.jpg\" onerror=this.src=\"userimages/no_profile_img.jpeg\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ><br /><a href="'+response['notification_id']+'">'+response['notification_content']+' </a><br />'+response['notification_time']+'<br /></div></div></div></div>');

      i = parseInt($("#mes").text()); $("#mes").text((i+response.num)); 
    }
}
});
}
setInterval(loadIt, 10000);


</script>

<? } }?>
```

But this is where I become stuck, because I want to use that notification_time to search the server for anything newer against the old one.. pass it back and put it in its designated div and then use that new notification_time on the next search instead of the same one I just used to get the new one, as that would be pretty pointless for what I'm wanting to achieve. We all know how social networks do it, problem is, I'll be the first one to admit, its confusing the life out of me...

Here is my Php which is obviously not complete.

```
if(isset($_GET['notification_time'])){

$id= mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_GET['notification_time']);
$user1_id= mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_SESSION['id']);
$json = array();
$com=mysqli_query($mysqli,"select notification_id,notification_content,notification_time,notification_triggeredby from notifications where notification_id > '$id' AND notification_targetuser='$user1_id' AND notification_status='1' ");
echo mysqli_error($mysqli);

$num = mysqli_num_rows($com);
if($num==1){

    $json['num'] = $num;
}else{
    $json['num'] = 0;
}
$resultArr = mysqli_fetch_array($com);
$json['notification_id'] = $resultArr['notification_id'];
$json['notification_content'] = $resultArr['notification_content'];
$json['notification_triggeredby'] = $resultArr['notification_triggeredby'];
$json['notification_time'] = $resultArr['notification_time'];
mysqli_free_result($com);

echo json_encode($json);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The careless global variable method would go something like this:

```
var notification_time="<?php echo $notification['notification_time'] ;?>"; // make global

function loadIt() {



$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "viewajax.php?notification_time="+notification_time,   
dataType:"json",
cache: false,
success: function(response){

    if (response.notificiation_time > notification_time) {
      $("#notif_actual_text-"+notification_time).prepend('<div class="notif_ui"><div class="notif_text"><div  id="notif_actual_text-'+response['notification_id']+'" class="notif_actual_text"><img border=\"1\" src=\"userimages/cropped'+response['notification_triggeredby']+'.jpg\" onerror=this.src=\"userimages/no_profile_img.jpeg\" width=\"40\" height=\"40\" ><br /><a href="'+response['notification_id']+'">'+response['notification_content']+' </a><br />'+response['notification_time']+'<br /></div></div></div></div>');

      i = parseInt($("#mes").text()); $("#mes").text((i+response.num)); 
    }
    notification_time = response.notificiation_time; // update global after each call
}
});
}
setInterval(loadIt, 10000);
```

Comment: Thank you victory, just trying to get past the NULL value if there is no new content.

Answer (score 0):

Quick way of getting to do that is if you store the 'notification_time' of the last query in a variable and check that variable against the new 'notification_time'

```
if(!isset($time)){
 $time = $notification['notification_time'];
}else{
 if($time < $notification['notification_time']){
  //update the div
  $time = $notification['notification_time'];
 }
}
```

Comment: Is this to go in the client side or server side?

Comment: add it on the same page you are calling mysqli_fetch_array() statement

Comment: I really don't see how this would work, considering the $time variable will be the exact same as the $notification['notification_time']

Comment: The new notification_time comes back through ajax as response.notification_time, and that is the one I need to use to search for the next set of new results if any.

Comment: all i am doing is checking the value that is stored in the time variable against the new notification time. once they don't match then it will show the new notification.

Comment: If you look at the query I check it in there. That is all working fine. What I'm trying to do is use that new notification I've just grabbed in the next ajax in its next search as it always searches the same result unless you refresh the page.

Answer (score 0):

Your `notification_time` variable needs to be updated each time by the `success` callback in your AJAX query.

So it needs to be outside your `loadIt` function. You might look into the [jQuery data method](http://api.jquery.com/data/). That would allow you to attach it somewhere like your notification list's parent element and avoid carelessly settling for a global.

A couple other suggestions:

- Looks like a typo here: `if (response.notificiation_time > notification_time) {`
- Avoid string concatenation in your AJAX callback for generating new DOM elements. Use jQuery elements `$newEl = $('<div />')...;` instead.
- Rewrite the SQL code at the top of your web page and remove that `while` loop. That loop gives entirely the wrong impression.